# Why does monodevelop on linux only provide an "any cpu" platform?

Tags: linux, monodevelop

I am building a c# console application on linux. But all of my applications I have built are in x86 architecture.

When I go into

`Solution Options` -> `Configurations` -> `Add`

the only `Platform` option I get is `Any CPU`

How do I get a 64-bit build configuration?

Comment: Can you verify that "Any CPU" builds x86 and not CLR bytecode?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not sure if i follow your question? 
i figured out my problem tho. i'll make an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Any CPU` will pick the best option for your particular architecture, but your project will still build x86 even if you are on x64 *if* you have your compiler set to x86.

Somehow my `Project Options` -> `Build` -> `Compiler` -> `Platform Target` got set to x86. I'm not sure if it was me updating Xamarin studio / monodevelop or what that caused that to get reverted to x86 but at some point i had correctly set that to x64.

Now that I moved the compiler back to x64 and rebuilt, I have a 64 bit application building again!

So something to watch out for if you are someone else who is seeing that same problem.